# Getting a bot to print the text of a message from its id

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to get a bot to print the text of a discord message that a user has reacted to. This is what I have so far:

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    print(payload)
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    print("message text here")
```

Weirdly the object await channel.fetch_message(id) sgives doesn't seem to include the text of the message.

Comment: You didn't define the `id` in the `fetch_message(id)`.

Comment: I've now fixed that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must assign fetched message to a variable. For example `message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)`. Then you can get it's content with `message.content`.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    print(payload)
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    print(message.content)
```

Comment: I think the second last line should be message =await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) but thanks so much for helping! i reallyt appreciate it!